# How to have requests in a thread group where a set of requests has a same data field (which is different from other sets)?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have two separate thread groups in jmeter,

**First Thread Group**: All the Users corresponding to first thread group are responsible to hit an API which creates a user and return userId in response

**Second Thread Group**: All the Users corresponding to second thread group are responsible to hit an API which uploads photo for created users and uses userId (returned in previous response) as its request data.

I have used InterThreadCommunication plugin of jmeter and so userID from response of API hit of first thread group get mapped to request data of API hits of second thread group.

The problem is that in Thread Group 2, I need to run upload image of user 5 times (in order to have a set of images corresponding to each user). How can I extend InterThreadCommunication functionality to map one userId from threadGroup1 to 5 requests of threadGroup2 (and similarly another userId to another 5 requests)

**Current Implementation:**

**Thread Group 1:**

jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor:

FIFO Queue Name to put Data in: *userIdList*

valueToPut: $*userId*

**Thread Group 2:**

jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor

FIFO Queue Name to get Data from : *userIdList*

variable name to store Data: *userId*

**Thread Group 2 request data** , I am using value as $*userId*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get it once using [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) and execute the request 5 times using [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

If Inter-Thread Communication Plugin is not flexible enough to fit your needs you can always switch to another approach of passing the values between Thread Groups, i.e.

1. Use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination to store the value in 1st Thread Group like:

   ```
   ${__setProperty(userid_${__threadNum}, YOUR_VALUE_HERE,)}
   ```
2. Use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and __threadNum() functions combination to read the value in 2nd Thread Group like:

   ```
    ${__P(userid_${__threadNum},)}
   ```

   [image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.